# How to speed up sass-compilation?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sass, gruntjs, gulp

When compiling sass I tend to have very long compilation times (up to 9 seconds on the current mid-scale project) on my otherwise very fast laptop with an ssd. I'm using sass via [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) ass a grunt task, but the compilation times don't differ much when running sass directly from the command line. [Libsass](https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass) on the other hand just needs around 100ms for the same project, but it doesn't support several features I need. So I would like to know what possibilities I have to speed up the compilation process?

Splitting up files helps of course, but are there other ways to do so with less side-effects?

*Edit:*
In addition I would be also glad for an explanation how libsass could so much faster than ruby-sass. Somehow I highly doubt that it is just because ruby is so much slower than C/C++. Or am I wrong here?

*Edit2:*
While I'm using Ubuntu, the same project is compiled in 2 seconds on a macbook pro, which is supposed to be slower, when it comes to the hardware, so this might be related to linux somehow.

Comment: "Somehow I highly doubt that it is just because ruby is so much slower than C/C++. Or am I wrong here?" Ruby is a dynamically typed interpreted language. It is many times slower than C++, as much as 100x slower in some cases: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=yarv&lang2=gpp&data=u64q

Comment: @thexacre thank you very much for pointing that out. I was aware dynamical languages are slower, also much slower, but not that the difference is this huge for ruby and c. But this still leaves a factor of around 5 of ruby sass being slower.

Comment: Libsass is not the same thing as Sass.  It does not have the full set of features Sass offers.  It is not uncommon to see the incorrect results when using Libsass.  That said, this may be of interest:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1019

Comment: Guardian reported speeding up their Sass compilation from 27 seconds to 3.6 seconds with node-sass (https://twitter.com/patrickhamann/status/565819491356262400). If that discrepancy continues, I can see libsass becoming the de facto standard.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the libsass compatibility situation has improved rather significantly since this question was asked. It's not perfect yet, but it's good enough for our (very large) SASS code base. A couple of resources:

https://github.com/sass/libsass/wiki/The-LibSass-Compatibility-Plan
http://sass-compatibility.github.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've found out so far:

- **changing ruby-version:** I had ruby 2.1.2 and sass 3.3.8 installed (current latest stables). After uninstalling all the previous (unused?) sass versions I had a speed increase of 1 second. Installing ruby 1.9.3 and then 2.0.0 everything compiles in around 2 seconds now (for both ruby versions). :) I'm still open to further suggestions though.

*Only grunt related:*

- **update-autoprefixer:** If you're using [grunt-autoprefixer](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) then I strongly suggest you to update it to the newest version (1.0.0 atm). I had a spead increase from 13 to 4 seconds in one of my projects. The update also fixes the broken source maps issue.
- **use jit-grunt instead of load-grunt-tasks:** If you're using grunt-load-tasks consider using [jit grunt](https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt) instead. There is a significant speed increse.